# How to Find Previously Created EC2 Instance, Elastic IP and Security Group Inbound Rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group, elastic-ip

I created an EC2 instance almost a year ago. A few months ago, I could no longer find the EC2 instance in the EC2 management page but I could still SSH into my instance and see my website with the Elastic IP it was on.

Now, I had to change my IP and went to update security group inbound rule for SSH. However, I could not find the previous inbound rules I set: `80`, `443`, and `22`.

I can't even find the Elastic IP but I still can access my website. I see that my instance is now considered a VPC.

How can I access my EC2 instance, Elastic IP, and security group inbound rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're in the correct region, you can only see resources in the region that you currently have selected.

To get this run `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone`.

Ignore the letter at the end to get the region, rather than AZ. For example if it returns `eu-west-1b` then `eu-west-1` would be the region.

Comment: My goodness, this was the issue. I absolutely do not recall changing the region at any point. I wonder if Amazon detected my physical location and changed the region in AWS between when I created the instance and a few months ago.

Comment: Sometimes if you access a global service such as IAM or CloudFront it sets your region as us-east-1. Glad this is now resolved for you, have a great weekend :)